# PHP Redirect after delay or adding key to header

Tags: php

So I am trying to sort a redirect in PHP after a user has submitted a form.

User presses submit on form > They are forwarded to a please wait page [backend is building folders/files based on their form input] > After a specified amount of time they are forwarded on to a page based on their input. If it was just a redirect after an amount of time I'd use JS but I need to use GET function to grab the key and then insert that into PHP so they can get forwarded onto the next page. So far I've got this which works individually BUT of course together it just loads the please wait page and then doesn't forward them on after the sleep time:

```
<?php

include('pleasewait.html');

sleep(20);



$url = $_GET['Key'];

header('location: http://example.com/test/'.$url);

?>
```

But could also do

```
<?php 
include('pleasewait.html');


  header( "refresh:5; url=example.com/[NEED KEY ADDED HERE]" ); 
?>
```

After user input they go to example.com?name=KEY - I just need a user to see "We're redirecting you" page first and then forward them on to the next page which is example.com/[KEY] after 10 seconds say. Thanks!

Comment: use meta redirect

Comment: PHP is not the way to do this, as PHP works on the server and then output's the finished data to the browser. You want something more interactive such as a `<meta>` tag or Javascript.

Comment: Why do you need a delay before redirection, simply send people straight to the new page?

Comment: Meta redirect was what I was planning to do but wasn't sure how to input Key data into the url? I need a delay as it takes several seconds to build the page and sending them right there sends them to a blank page which they would need to refresh themselves.

Comment: i'd build it into the actual output page, when the user arrives you give them status `IF` building is complete show the dashboard page `ELSE` your dashboard is still building, check back i a minute or meta redirect every 30 seconds .. this way you are certain the user sees a proper dashboard when the task completes, do not assume a simple timeout is enough (sometimes it is not)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) / [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and processing php inside html a common way is to use a template file and echo its content. Where you "define" your "override data" vars in braces "{KEY}" and replace it by [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).
For complex structures of course this is not ideal. But for common pages its not so bad.

In my following example I show you a way of redirection using meta js and noscript.

**redirect.tpl**

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Redirection</title>

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="private, no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="{TIMEOUT}; URL={REDIRURL}">
<meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top">
<meta name="audience" content="all">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,follow">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
<meta name="description" content="">

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
div
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*]]>*/
</style>

</head>

<body scroll="auto" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000" alink="#FFFF00" text="#000000">

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function(){location.href="{REDIRURL}"} , ({TIMEOUT}*1000)); 
  </script>

  <noscript>
    <div align="center" style="position:absolute; text-align:center; background-color:#D5E9FD; border:2px solid #666666; top:50%; left:50%; width:512px; height:150px; margin-left:-256px; margin-top:-75px; visibility:visible; z-index:1;">
      <br><br>
      <b>Redirecting...</b><br><br>You should be automatically redirected in {TIMEOUT} seconds. If not, <a href="{REDIRURL}" target="_top">click here</a>.<br>
    </div>
  </noscript>

</body>

</html>
```

**php**

```
<?php 
   $url = "http://example.com/test/test.php?Key=" . urlencode($_GET['Key']);
   $timeout = 20;
   $tpl = file_get_contents("redirect.tpl");
   $tpl = str_replace("{TIMEOUT}", $timeout, $tpl);
   $tpl = str_replace("{REDIRURL}", $url, $tpl);
   exit($tpl);
?>
```

Side note: I wonder about the amount of PHP questions concerning storing vars over serveral requests [globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) GET, POST, COOKIE and especially [SESSIONS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) which should really be the basic of the basics to start with. This is not offense. Just wondering.

Hope this will help you a little. Regards

Comment: setTimeout is in millisecons of course, sorry need to edit that ;)